# EPIC debugging freezes when running threaded code

Tags: multithreading, perl, debugging, epic

My epic debugger seems to reliable freeze every time I try to debug code I inherited.  In fact all of eclipse will freeze until I kill Perl.  I'm trying to determine where to look for the failure and how to minimize or remove it, but the fact that I'm brand new to perl doesn't help.

I suspect the issue is with threads, due to the fact that we have two types of threads, perl doesn't do threads well, and the threads are..not pretty.  In this case we want to run a number of scripts.  We do this by starting up n perl threads.  Each of these threads does very little besides making a call to the operating system to run the scripts using sh and waiting on it.  These scripts take some time, I assume they are running and if I were willing to wait 2-5 hours the debugged program would finish properly, but that doesn't help with my debugging.

I presume the combination of perl threads waiting on the OS is causing some sort of blocking state that freezes the entire Perl program, due to the limited quasi-threading of perl?  Can anyone confirm if that would happen, and if that were to happen would it freeze the debugger and thus all of eclipse as well?  Is there any way to keep debugger functionality once threads are spawned, or even simply prevent it from freezing my eclipse entirely when it happens?